# How to Access Azure Login Api, without using the login link provided by the Normal Azure Auth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

I seem to find in every part of stack overflow,
any tutorial

that azure must be log in, before I get the code to access the refresh token

```
const config = {
auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    authority: process.env.AUTHORITY,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
},
system: {
    loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
            console.log(message);
        },
        piiLoggingEnabled: false,
        logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
       }
   }
};
const authCodeUrlParameters = {
scopes: ["user.read","user.write"],
redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URL,
};

pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
// res.redirect(response);
console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
console.log(authCodeUrlParameters);
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
const tokenRequest = {
    code: req.query.code,
    scopes: ["user.read"],
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
};

pca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
    console.log("\nResponse: \n:", response);
    res.sendStatus(200);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
});
});
```

getAuthCodeUrl returns a link which I would need to login to get my code
which then would I need to use to get the tokens and have my refresh token there.

but I don't want to access the link since I'm using console not GUI,

My Mind is at the breaking point I don't know what to do.
I just need the API for One Drive,
so I can Upload my file.

majority in the stackoverflow,
has a code that requires a refresh token

I can't get the refresh token without accessing the link.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find it,
you should find the Client Credentials,

I use request headers
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant) id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

tenant id is located in app registration in azure

then make sure the grant type is
grant_type: 'client_credentials',
scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' //not sure if this is changeable yet

either use request lib or axios
get put post head

hope it helps other people when they find this issue